# NSString is returning as NULL while Importing from ViewController Class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

NSString is returning as NULL while Importing from ViewController Class

were i want to import the string variable from 1st class to second class..but its not importing

please find met code below for your reference

```
ViewController:


@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

NSString * string;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString * string;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize string;

-(IBAction) login:(id) sender{
string = @"HI";
}

class2:

#import"ViewController.h"

@interface class2 : UIViewController{
ViewController * vc;
NSString * string1;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString * string1;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize string1;

-(IBAction) login:(id) sender{
NSLog(@"%@",vc.string);

@end
}
```

Where NSLog is returning NULL!!!!

Kindly help me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: How you are passing details are one view controller to another view controller? Or what is your heirarchy of view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear about your code but if you want to send string from class1 to class2 then you can follow below method:

1.Declare property in class2, same as you have declare:

```
NSString * string1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString * string1;

@synthesize string1;
```

2.Then in class1 where you are navigating to class2 (from where you are initializing class2) just assign your string1 the required value as follows:

```
class2Obj.string1 = @"Hi";
```

and In class2 you can access string1.

Comment: Hi Nuzhat in class1 i wrote {class2Obj.string1 = @"Hi";} now in class 2 i should just use NSLog@"%@",string1; or old one????

Comment: Yes you can use NSLog(@"%@",string1) or NSLog(@"%@",self.string1), since it is a property.

Comment: Are you assigning string1 NULL somewhere in your class2?

Comment: no NuZhat and also when i try to import Viewcontoller in interface it is not importing of second class but importing @implementation of second class

Comment: class2 * lp= [[logPage alloc]initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
       lp.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
       [self presentModalViewController:lp animated: YES];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13027/discussion-between-nuzhat-zari-and-pradeepj)

Comment: Put #import"logPage.h" in firstviewController.m, then while transiting, put logPage * lp= [[logPage alloc]init]; lp.string1 = @"your value";lp.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; [self presentModalViewController:lp animated: YES];

Answer (score 0):

@pradeepj its returning `Null` because your `vc` instance is also `Null`, i am not sure how are you getting instance of `vc`. If you are using a `UINavigationController` then you can get instance of `vc` by using `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

The second class doesn't just automatically get a reference to the same instance of class1 where you set the string value. Your class2 needs to have a property that is set possibly from class1 that references the instance of class 1 where you set the string

//in class 1

```
Class2 *vc = [[Class2 alloc] init];
vc.class1 = self;

[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

just change:

```
-(IBAction) login:(id) sender{
string = @"HI";
}
```

to

```
-(IBAction) login:(id) sender{
self.string = @"HI";
}
```

this will retain ur variable so that you may find it elsewhere. Just be sure that you have assigned the `vc` variable correctly before fetching value of `string` variable.